# Show $\sqrt{a^2-ab+b^2}+\sqrt{b^2-bc+c^2} \geq \sqrt{a^2+ac+c^2}$

Tags: inequality

Can someone help me with this problem:
Let $a$, $b$, $c$ be positive numbers. Show that:
$\sqrt{a^2-ab+b^2}+\sqrt{b^2-bc+c^2} \geq \sqrt{a^2+ac+c^2}$

Comment: Why this problem is getting upvotes even if (till now) there is no indication of OP's effort in the post?

Comment: Another approach is to define a function and find its extrema but CS is more than elegant!

Comment: Your question was put on hold, the message above (and possibly comments) should give an explanation why. (In particular, [this link](http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/a/9960) might be useful.) You might try to edit your question to address these issues. Note that the next edit puts your post in the review queue, where users can vote to reopen this. (Therefore it would be good to avoid minor edits and improve your question as much as possible with the next edit.)

Comment: For the record, I upvoted the question because the problem result and solution are really nice; just because a post doesn't meet math.SE's suggested question guidelines doesn't mean everybody has to downvote it and try to close it. Of course I respect the decision of those who do take these measures; I just believe that the niceness of these questions contributes more to the community than the "missing context" aspect of them detracts from it.

Comment: $\newcommand{\o}{\omega}$
Letting $\o=e^{2\pi i/3}=-\frac{1}{2}+\left(\frac{\sqrt{3}}{2}\right)i$, then note that
$$|a+b\o|=\sqrt{a^2-ab+b^2}$$
([See the Wikipedia article on Eisenstein integers](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Eisenstein_integer).)
Also, $|\o|=1$ so that
$$|b\o+c\o^2|=|\o\cdot(b+c\o)|=|b+c\o|=\sqrt{b^2-bc+c^2}$$
and $-\o^2=\o+1$ so that
$$|a-c\o^2|=|(a+c)+c\o|=\sqrt{(a+c)^2-(a+c)c+c^2}=\sqrt{a^2+ac+c^2}$$
By the triangle inequality,
$$|a+b\o|+|b\o+c\o^2| \geq|(a+b\o)-(b\o+c\o^2)|= |a-c\o^2|$$
which becomes
$$\sqrt{a^2-ab+b^2}+\sqrt{b^2-bc+c^2}\geq\sqrt{a^2+ac+c^2}$$

Answer (score 14, accepted):

Let $OA=a, OB=b, OC=c, \angle AOB=60^{\circ}, \angle COB=60^{\circ}$

[image]

Then 
$$AB+BC\ge AC\Leftrightarrow\sqrt{a^2-ab+b^2}+\sqrt{b^2-bc+c^2} \geq \sqrt{a^2+ac+c^2}$$

Comment: +1 Elegant! Although I preferred it before the addition!

Answer (score 2):

As an algebraic alternative to @Roman83's beautiful geometric solution.

Squaring both sides and applying Cauchy-Schwarz inequality \begin{align*}
\sqrt{(a^2-ab+b^2)(b^2-bc+c^2)} &= \sqrt{\left[\left(b-\frac{a}2\right)^2 + \frac{3a^2}{4}\right]\left[\left(b-\frac{c}{2}\right)^2 + \frac{3c^2}{4}\right]} \\
&\geq \left|\left(b-\frac{a}{2}\right)\left(b-\frac{c}{2}\right)\right| + \frac{3ac}{4}
\end{align*}
The problem is reduced to $\left|(2b-a)(2b-c)\right| \ge -(2b-a)(2b-c)$, which is trivial.